# Martingale (stochastic analysis)

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals, poisson-distribution

Let $N_t$ denote a Poisson process with intensity λ > 0, and let $M_t = N_t − λt$ be the
compensated martingale of N .

I want to verify that the process Y given by $Y_t = \int_{0}^{t} N_{s-} dM_s$ is a martingale by invocating a general theorem of stochastic analysis.

Thank you

Comment: @ Kened Yassine : $N_t$ the integrand is in $L^2$ which is enough. Best regards